# PHP Listener Script for Paypal Webhooks

Tags: php, json, paypal, webhooks, paypal-webhooks

I'm having trouble writing a PHP listener script for Paypal notification webhooks. I simply need a script to listen for and request the Paypal json data. I have created one for Stripe successfully, thanks to plenty of online documentation. This is what I have:

```
<?php require_once('./lib/Stripe.php');
    Stripe::setApiKey("my_secret_stripe_key");

    $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
    $event_json = json_decode($input);

    // then I request the json data from a Stripe event... //
    $event_json->type == 'charge.succeeded'
    // etc... //
?>
```

I just need something similar to handle Paypal event json.

Comment: Have you tried reading [their docs about this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/#listener)? What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 3):

PayPal just released a new version, PayPal PHP-SDK 1.4.0;
this has a webhook listener.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/releases/tag/v1.4.0

The file is ValidateWebhookEvent.php

It is in the samples.
PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/notifications/ValidateWebhookEvent.php

The docs are here
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Webhook-Validation

Comment: PayPal PHP-SDK is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

I used this [tutorial on http://code.tutsplus.com/](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/paypal-integration-part-3-paypal-webhooks--cms-22919) which was very helpful. You might also want to take a look at [the webhook validation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Webhook-Validation).